# Substring from a string in python

Tags: python

Remove the substring `t` from a string `s`, repeatedly and print the number of steps involved to do the same.

For Example: `t = ab`, `s = aabb`. In the first step, we check if `t` is contained within `s`. Here, `t` is contained in the middle i.e. `a(ab)b`. So, we will remove it and the resultant will be ab and increment the `count` value by 1. We again check if `t` is contained within `s`. Now, `t` is equal to `s` i.e. `(ab)`. So, we remove that from `s` and increment the `count`. So, since t is no more contained in `s`, we stop and print the `count` value, which is 2 in this case.

Comment: seems like a homework question, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried but complete error....can you send me the code in python

Comment: @riteshsinha Please share the code that you have tried and then maybe someone can help find the bug.

Comment: I wrote a smal script that works just fine, however it seems as if you have a homework so I will need to see some sort of an attempt before I will help you. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check if this answers your question.

```
t ='ab'
s= 'aabb'
count=0
while t in s:
    s = s.replace(t,'')
    count+=1
print(count)
```